# Generalization of a property of finite nilpotent groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism, nilpotent-groups, maximal-subgroup

Let $G$ be a finite nilpotent group and $M$ be a maximal subgroup of $G$.
If $H$ is a proper non-trivial subgroup of $G$ such that $H\not\leq M$, 
then we can show that $H\cap M$ is a maximal subgroup of $H$. 
Because every maximal subgroup of $G$ is normal and using 
second isomorphism theorem  implies that $|H:H\cap M|$ is prime.

Could we generalize this property for NON-nilpotent groups?

Any proof or counterexample will be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

According to spin's nice point let me add this assumption to the question:

"Let $H\cap M\neq 1$".

Comment: There are many small counterexamples. I suggest you try looking for one. For example, you could look for examples where $H \cap M = 1$ but $H$ is not cyclic of prime order.

Comment: To get $H \cap M \ne 1$, just take a direct product with any nontrivial group.

Comment: Dear professor Holt please give me a little more details if it is possible. thank you so much!